Ключевое слово volatile в C
Я не понимаю его значение, сколько не гуглил, везде написано мыло или теория которая без практического кода мало что говорит, кто может объяснить, что такое volatile и как его использовать со смыслом?

volatile заставляет компилятор не оптимизировать запись/чтение в переменную (не заменять ее на регистр а всегда писать в оперативную память, читать и писать ровно когда сказали, ...).
Если вы программируете какую-то железку, где запись по специальным адресам в памяти вызывает какие-то специальные эффекты (какой-нибудь memory-mapped IO), то volatile нужен, чтобы компилятор не сделал ничего странного с этой записью в память (не убрал ее оптимизацией, или еще что-нибудь).
Или вот еще пример: sig_atomic_t. Тут мануал говорит, что внутри обработчика std::signal можно использовать volatile переменные для связи с внешним миром.
Еще их можно использовать для бенчмарков, чтобы компилятор не выкидывал вычисления, которые вы замеряете (записать результат в volatile переменную).
Еще: до С++26 бесконечные циклы считались UB, если в их теле нет никакой связи с внешним миром, поэтому вместо пустого тела втыкали какой-нибудь i++ на volatile переменной. В C++26 разрешили бесконечные циклы с пустым телом (с непустым до сих пор нелегально). В C, я так понимаю, они в любом виде легальны.
Еще на asm ассемблерных вставках у него какой-то специальный смысл; читайте мануал.
Для чего не надо использовать:

Многопоточность - незнающие люди пытаются использовать их для коммуниации между потоками. Правильно - использовать std::atomic (в C++) и _Atomic (в C).
Подпирание костылем UB - бывает так что код крашит на ровном месте, но только с включенными оптимизациями (обычно из-за кривых рук и UB). Иногда volatile исправляет такой краш, но вместо этого лучше починить UB.


Комментарии были перемещены в чат; пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь. Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с назначением комментариев. Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть ответами, размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.
